# How to get facebook fan page name in my facebook tab application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I created a facebook tab application that allow facebook fan page admin to add it as tab into their fan page. So far, everything works well except that i couln't **get the "Fan page name"**? I would like to show it in my facebook application as a title say "**My Fan Page Name**'s twitter application".

On top of that, how do i get the **list of their facebook fan page followers**?

I'm using ASP MVC4 facebook template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When some user comes to your Page Tab App, Facebook posts you signed_request.
Quoting from Facebook's [Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

> When a user selects your Page Tab, you will receive the signed_request parameter with one additional parameter, **page**. This parameter contains a JSON object with an **id** (the page id of the current page), **admin** (if the user is a admin of the page), and **liked** (if the user has liked the page).

You can utilize the **id** that you get to retrieve the information you require, **Name of Page**.

Although you can't get the **list of User's** who have liked that page, but you can get the count of likes the Page has.

Answer (score 1):

download the sdk from http://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook.CSharp.SDK/

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();
//your application id and secret from https://developers.facebook.com/apps
config.Add("appId", "3955.......");
config.Add("secret", "4c1d...............");
config.Add("fileUpload", true); //optional

FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(config);
var fields = client.getSignedRequest()["page"] as Dictionary<string, object>;


var graphApiCall = new FacebookGraphApiRequest();
graphApiCall.Method = FacebookApiMethodType.GET;
graphApiCall.Path = fields["id"];
graphApiCall.Params = null;
//this is the json string that holds all the json string.
Response.Write(client.api(graphApiCall));
```